# After installing only rails gem version 5.0.0, the command 'rails -v' prints 'Rails 5.0.1'. Why?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-5

I need to stick with Rails 5.0.0 for now. I'm using a gemset (rails500) and ruby-2.3.3 with rvm. I told rvm to use the gemset and uninstalled the other Rails version (5.0.1) from the gemset using the command 'gem uninstall rails'. After that I used the command 'gem install rails --version=5.0.0' to make sure my desired Rails is in the gemset.

Now when I do a 'rails -v' the response is 'Rails 5.0.1'. Why isn't it 'Rails 5.0.0'? When I do a "gem list | egrep '^rails '" the response is 'rails (5.0.0)'.

Related question: how can I be sure this version of rails is not 5.0.0?

Comment: you must to switch rvm to use desired ruby version and reopen your terminal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The apparent answer is given by ryanjm at
https://github.com/rubygems/rubygems/issues/542

```
$ gem uninstall railties -v 5.0.1
```

is necessary after

```
$ gem uninstall rails -v 5.0.1
```

Answer (score 0):

Please follow this for setting the rails version you want:

rvm has nothing to do with rails. rvm is used to manage multiple ruby installations. And each of your ruby installations can be associated with multiple gemsets. For instance, say you have ruby 1.9.3 installed and you created two gemsets for ruby 1.9.3: gemsetA and gemsetB. If you tell rvm to use ruby 1.9.3 with gemsetA, that means:

Your ruby programs will be executed by ruby 1.9.3.
Your ruby programs can require any gem in gemsetA (which then allows your program to use the methods (or classes) defined in gemsetA), but any gems in gemsetB cannot be seen by your ruby program.
Here's a concrete example:

```
~$ rvm list

   rvm rubies

   ruby-1.8.7-p370 [ i686 ]
   * ruby-1.9.3-p194 [ x86_64 ]
   => ruby-2.0.0-p0 [ x86_64 ]
   ruby-2.0.0-p247 [ x86_64 ]

# => - current
# =* - current && default
#  * - default


~$ rvm use 1.9.3-p194
Using /Users/7stud/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194
.
```

~$ rvm gemset list   (This lists only the gemsets for the current ruby version)

gemsets for ruby-1.9.3-p194 (found in /Users/7stud/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194)
=> (default)
global
programming
rails3tutorial
rails4

~$ rvm gemset use programming
Using ruby-1.9.3-p194 with gemset programming
After I do that, my ruby programs will be executed by ruby 1.9.3 and any gems in the programming gemset can be required into my ruby program. You can use a shortcut to perform both those commands in one step:

rvm use ruby 1.9.3-p194@programming
You just combine the ruby version and the gemset with an '@' between them.

$ rails -v
Rails 4.0.0
This is because the current gemset contains the gem for rails 4.0.0. If you want to see $ rails -v output Rails 3.2.14, then you need to tell rvm to switch to a gemset that contains the rails 3.2.14 gem.

However, you can make rvm automatically switch to the proper rails version and gemset for your rails project. In your Gemfile, add a comment after the ruby version:

ruby '2.0.0'

## ruby-gemset=railstutorial4_gems

Then whenever you switch to the directory containing your rails project, rvm will automatically switch the current ruby to ruby 2.0.0 and the current gemset to railstutorial4_gems. If you change directories out of your rails app, rvm will change the current ruby and the current gemset back to what they were.

I'm just a rails beginner, but here are the steps I use to create a new project, which are straight out of the railstutorial book (http://ruby.railstutorial.org/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-book)

1)

.../rails_projects$ rvm use @ --create

e.g.

.../rails_projects$ rvm use ruby-1.9.3-p194@myapp_gemset --create
2)

.../rails_projects$ gem install rails --version 3.2.14
Because the current gemset is the myapp gemset, that command installs the rails 3.2.14 gem into the myapp gemset.

3)

.../rails_projects$ rails new myapp
.../rails_projects$ cd myapp
The current gemset is still myapp_gemset.

4)

.../rails_projects/myapp$ rails -v
Rails 3.2.14
In case anyone was wondering what the heck the following two gemsets are all about:

gemsets for ruby-1.9.3-p194 (found in /Users/7stud/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194)

=> (default)
global
rvm creates those two gemsets for every ruby version you install. After you install a ruby version, if you don't create a gemset yourself for that ruby version, and you install a gem, then the gem goes into the (default) gemset. And, if you want all your gemsets to contain a certain gem, you can switch to the global gemset and install the gem there.

Update: -------

To maintain compatibility with other ruby version managers, you can specify the ruby version and gemset name for your project in a different file rather than in the Gemfile:

$ cd ~/rails_projects/myapp

~/rails_projects/myapp$ echo 2.0.0 > .ruby-version
~/rails_projects/myapp$ echo myapp_gemset > .ruby-gemset
You'll still get the same automatic ruby version and gemset switching when you cd into your project's directory. See the rvm docs here.

Comment: I'm not sure whether my question was unclear or you read it wrong. I said I ran the commands to uninstall Rails version (5.0.1) from the current gemset and to install Rails version 5.0.0 in its place. Now 'rails -v' and 'gem list' print different version numbers for rails.